# SQLAlchemy: How to order query results (order_by) on a relationship's field?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by, field, relationship

## Models

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import Unicode
from sqlalchemy import TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

BaseModel = declarative_base()

class Base(BaseModel):
   __tablename__ = 'base'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   location = Column(Unicode(12), ForeignKey("locationterrain.location"), unique=True,)
   name = Column(Unicode(45))
   ownerid =  Column(Integer,ForeignKey("player.id"))
   occupierid =  Column(Integer, ForeignKey("player.id"))
   submitid =  Column(Integer,ForeignKey("player.id"))
   updateid =  Column(Integer,ForeignKey("player.id"))
   owner = relationship("Player",
         primaryjoin='Base.ownerid==Player.id',
         join_depth=3,
         lazy='joined')
   occupier= relationship("Player",
         primaryjoin='Base.occupierid==Player.id',
         join_depth=3,
         lazy='joined')
   submitter = relationship("Player",
         primaryjoin='Base.submitid== Player.id',
         join_depth=3,
         lazy='joined')
   updater= relationship("Player",
         primaryjoin='Base.updateid== Player.id',
         join_depth=3,
         lazy='joined')


class Player(BaseModel):
   __tablename__ = 'player'
   id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("guildmember.playerid"), primary_key=True)
   name =  Column(Unicode(45))
```

## Searching

```
bases = dbsession.query(Base)
bases = bases.order_by(Base.owner.name)
```

This doesn't work .... I've searched everywhere and read the documentation.
But I just don't see how I can sort my (Base) query on their 'owner' relationship's name.

It always results in:

```
 AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'name'
```

This must be easy... but I don't see it. Also looked into Comparators, which seemed logical, but I don't see where the query part for the ORDER BY is generated or what I should be returning since everything is generated dynamically. And making a comparator for each of my 'player' relationships to do a simple thing seems over complicated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

SQLAlchemy wants you to think in terms of SQL.   If you do a query for "Base", that's:

```
SELECT * FROM base
```

easy.  So how, in SQL, would you select the rows from "base" and order by the "name" column in a totally different table, that is, "player"?   You use a join:

```
SELECT base.* FROM base JOIN player ON base.ownerid=player.id ORDER BY player.name
```

SQLAlchemy has you use the identical thought process - you join():

```
session.query(Base).join(Base.owner).order_by(Player.name)
```

Comment: That makes sense. But that does mean that I can only join one of the player relationships at a time right?  Joining more (for whatever reason.. ) means breaking stuff.

So if I want to order by updater, I have to do this:
<code>session.query(Base).join(Base.updater).order_by(Player.name) </code>

or 'occupier':
       session.query(Base).join(Base.occupier).order_by(Player.name)

Comment: you can join to a certain table any number of times using aliases of that table.  again this is a SQL concept, so knowing how to solve the problem in SQL means you'd know how to solve it in SQLAlchemy.  Aliasing is first introduced at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-aliases.

Comment: This answer would filter out any `base` objects where `base.ownerid` is null. Do you know how to modify the approach to order by relationship values, but not exclude objects which have no values in the relationship? (perhaps ordering the ones without the relationship last or first)

Comment: In case anyone is curious I included null relationships by just forcing a left join. In sqlalchemy that's done using `outerjoin` instead of `join`.

Comment: @zzzeek How can we achieve this if the related field is for a one-many relationship i.e. in case where the related field contains a collection, because in that we first need to order/sort the related collection itself for correctly ordered Parent(One side in one-to-many relation) result set. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72305546/how-to-sort-the-relationship-data-by-user-defined-field-before-ordering-the-pare

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `order_by` argument

note here `order_by` argument in `relationship` from sqlalchemy.orm
Please consider parent-children relationship here as many-to-many.

```py
class Parent(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "parent"

    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    
    children = relationship(
        'Children',
        secondary=child_parent_mapping,
        backref=backref(
            'parents',
        ),
        order_by="Parent.order_id",
    )
```