# Order results by link defined in 'relationship'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have tables that I want to do an ORM based query.

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, server_default="1", nullable=False)
    is_deleted = Column(Boolean, server_default="0", nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable = False, default=func.now())
    first_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    surname_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, server_default="1", nullable=False)
    is_deleted = Column(Boolean, server_default="0", nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable = False, default=func.now())
    first_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    surname_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    appointments = relationship("ChildAppointment", backref="child")

class ParentChild(Base):
    '''provides a many to many relationship for parent and child'''
    __tablename__ = 'parent_child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, server_default="1")
    is_deleted = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, server_default="0")
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), nullable=False)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))

    parents = relationship("Parent", backref="parent_child")
    children = relationship("Child", backref="parent_child")

class ChildAppointment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child_appointment'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, server_default="1")
    is_deleted = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, server_default="0")
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable = False, default=func.now())
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
    date_appointment = Column(DateTime, nullable = False)
```

I want to query Table `ParentChild` and through SQLAlchemy relationship magic, I want to get the latest appointment date for the child meaning I need the result ordered by `date_appointment` in the child table.

I have followed the example by @zeek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9862111/1082673) and I've come up with the following:

```
for data in session.query(ParentChild).join(Child.appointments).filter(ParentChild.parent_id == 1).\
        order_by(Child.appointments.date_appointment.desc()).all():
```

However, I get the error `attributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Child.appointments has an attribute 'date_appointment'`

My scenario breaks what was given in that link because mine goes an extra table in as I have 4 tables so am unable to adapt his answer to suit mine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: First of all, for the join condition, you would want to specify it as a kind of chain:

- ParentChild -> Child
- Child -> ChildAppointment

That is done like this:

```
session.query(ParentChild).join(ParentChild.children).join(Child.appointments)
```

This will yield the correct join. I think if it is unambigous you could also do this:

```
session.query(ParentChild).join(Child).join(ChildAppointment)
```

But you'd have to try it out.

The real error, however, comes from this part:

```
Child.appointments.date_appointment
```

Instead it should look like this:

```
ChildAppointment.date_appointment
```

SQLAlchemy already knows how to get this `ChildAppointment` related to `Child` and `ParentChild` because you specified it in the `join`s above. And if you think about it in raw SQL terms it makes much more sense this way.

So you final solution:

```
session.query(ParentChild).join(ParentChild.children).join(Child.appointments).filter(ParentChild.parent_id == 1).order_by(ChildAppointment.date_appointment.desc()).all():
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked as expected.