# Using a nested value for a SQLAlchemy relationship order_by

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given these relationships:

```
A.children = [B...]
B.type = C
C.order = int
```

How can I specify the order of the `.children` relationship to order by `B.type.order`?

```
class A(Base):
    id       = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship(lambda: B, order_by=lambda: B.type.order)
    #                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    #                                           this doesn't work

class B(Base):
    C_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(C.id), primary_key=True)
    A_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(A.id), primary_key=True)

    type = relationship(lambda: C)

class C(Base):
    id       = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order    = Column(Integer)
```

Gives me:

> AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with `B.type` has an attribute 'order'

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9861990/102441) seems relevant, but I'm not sure how to fit that into the `order_by` kwarg

Comment: Your `B.type` is a relationship, it does not have any order attribute. The order_by needs to resolve to a column of table **B**. What you are trying to do is not even a column of B but it needs a JOIN to table C, and I don't think that can be done. Maybe look at this http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#using-column-property.

Comment: Another workaround would be to declare your relationship as `lazy="dynamic"` and then do `a.children.join(C).order_by(C.order).all()`

Comment: @dtheodor: Seems to have done the trick, although it would be nice if I didn't need to do an explicit join there

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it ought to work:

```
class A(Base):
    id       = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship(lambda: B, order_by=lambda: B._order)

class B(Base):
    C_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(C.id), primary_key=True)
    A_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(A.id), primary_key=True)

    type = relationship(lambda: C)
    _order = column_property(select([C.order]).where(C.id == C_id))

class C(Base):
    id       = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order    = Column(Integer)
```